# Pycharm Ubuntu Chromebook: Loading PyCharm after a shutdown causes files to become empty

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, chromebook

I have a chromebook with crouton ubuntu installed onto an SD card. I also have PyCharm installed.

When ever I work on a project, I save often, even have the auto save feature enabled.

But when I shutdown my chromebook gracefully, then load it back up later. my python files are still there but blank. It's happened several times now and as you can imagine, it's being quite annoying.

Has anyone else experienced this before? and does anyone know a fix?

Comment: That sounds like an OS or file system problem and might be off-topic.

Comment: If that's the case then I'm sorry, but it seems any programs I install stays on, so I assumed it was a pycharm issue